# How to replace deprecated HMSET in in node.js REDIS

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, node-redis

The Redis command HMSET has been [deprecated](https://redis.io/commands/hmset) since version 4. They suggest using HSET instead. But when trying that I get a different deprecation warning.
I was using: `db.hmset('key', {a: 1, b: 'c'})`. Now I tried to replace it with `db.hset` but that triggers:

```
node_redis: Deprecated: The HSET command contains a argument of type Object.
This is converted to "[object Object]" by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.
Please handle this in your code to make sure everything works as you intended it to.
```

What is the correct way to store an object in a Redis database?

The documentation for Redis HSET states: 'As of Redis 4.0.0, HSET is variadic and allows for multiple field/value pairs.' I want to store the whole object as it would be using `hmset` in the database, not its string representation.

Answer (score 2):

as described [here](https://github.com/NodeRedis/node-redis#commands), redis client dose not support objects in a command arguments.

To easily store an object in redis you can do:

```js
db.hset('key', ...Object.entries({a: 'a', b: 'b'}), (err) => {
  // ...
});
```

note that it'll ignore `Symbol` keys, and work only with "flat objects".

Comment: This has the same problem as doing an object. It triggers a warning: `node_redis: Deprecated: The HSET command contains a argument of type Array.
This is converted to “a,a” by using .toString() now and will return an error from v.3.0 on.`

Comment: I forgot to spread the entries, check the edited version

Answer (score 1):

For those using Typescript, the second argument of hSet can be an array of strings of this kind ['k1', 'v1', 'k2', 'v2',...]. So the following code works:

```
const obj: Record<string, string | number> = {a: 'a', n: 1};
await client.hSet('key', [...Object.entries(obj).flat()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that the second argument of `hset` must be a string. If it's not `.toString` will be applied to it. But as it will return `"[object Object]"` in your case, the warning triggers. Maybe use `JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 'c'})` as parameter instead

Comment: The documentation for Redis [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset) states:
 'As of Redis 4.0.0, HSET is variadic and allows for multiple field/value pairs.'
Your solution is not the same as doing HMSET. Because that would only save a single string. I want to store the whole object in the database.

Comment: Then modify your question, what exactly do you want the set values and hashes to be ? Because you could just save the json representation of your object and then parse it when you get it